# Force new posts to the top of query loop

Tags: wp-query

I have a query where the posts is ordered by title. I am trying to filter into the (main) query in order to have the newest (created in the last 14 days) on top of the loop. Below the newly created posts, the rest should be sorted as default.

I have tried the `posts_results` filter but that is fired after pagination is made, so if some of the new posts is at page 2 or greater, it is not possible to force them to the top.

I have also tried the `pre_get_posts` but I cannot find a suitable clause for the `orderby`-statement.

I have considered if it is needed to run an extra query inside `pre_get_posts` but I cannot see the path for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion using `posts_orderby` filter and `CASE`, [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) and [`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) (that outputs number of days) from MySQL for conditional SQL ordering:

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', function( $orderby, $q ) use (&$wpdb) {
    if( ! $q->is_main_query() ) { 
        return $orderby;
    }
    return $wpdb->prepare(
        'CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF( %i.post_date, NOW() ) <= 14
                THEN -UNIX_TIMESTAMP( %i.post_date )
            ELSE %i.post_title
         END ASC',
        "{$wpdb->posts}",
        "{$wpdb->posts}",
        "{$wpdb->posts}"
    );    
}, 10, 2 );
```

This might probably be simplified with e.g. numbered arguments like `%1$i` if that's supported by the new prepare-placeholder `%i` for table/field names.

To avoid using two order-by fields  with two cases, to handle both ASC and DESC ordering, I instead suggest using a single order-by field with a single ASC order by using negative unix timestamps for the date ordering.

Hope you can test this further.